# Are there any benefits to develop for ios in Mavericks ?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I have Snow Leopard and I want to upgrade so that I can start developing for iOS. I know I need 10.7 (Lion) but was wondering if there's any real benefit to upgrade to the latest OS (Mavericks) ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Xcode on the App Store (5.0.2) requires Mountain Lion (10.8.4), so that's a good reason to be running at least 10.8. Always good to use the latest tools.

And really you might as well just upgrade to Mavericks seeing as the upgrade is free.

Comment: I might as well, normally I download the minimum required because of compatibility issues, and also because I don't want the new operating system to slow down my computer. Thanks Richard.